# iPhone App: Application Error when start in a special scenario

Tags: iphone, core-data, persistent-storage

The app was installed and has not been used for about one day, then it is updated when syncing via iTunes, then I start the app it says:

"Application Error: An unresolved error has occurred. Please quit the application and try again"

on starts, it is an alert view with no button to tap, then the app resets itself but still shows the same thing, even if I restart the device. The only way to get rid of it is to remove the app and reinstall.

edit:
the error message is posted by:

```
if (![__persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeURL options:options error:&error])
{
    NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    // SHOW THAT ERROR MESSAGE
}
```

So what could be the reason of it? I guess it is caused by the tester syncing the app which corrupted the database(but the database model is not changed between two versions)?

Thanks!

Comment: Please post the full userInfo. Andrew